# Remover linha específica de arquivos no linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Preciso remover uma determinada linha em um arquivo `crontab` ex:

```
* * * * * root /home/linaro/funcao1.sh
* * * * * root /home/linaro/funcao3.sh
* * * * * root /home/linaro/funcao4.sh
* * * * * root /home/linaro/funcao5.sh
```

gostaria de apagar a linha

```
* * * * * root /home/linaro/funcao4.sh
```

Lembrando que esse file não esta no `crontab` ele sera importado de acordo com o script

tentei utilizar o `sed` mas minha deficiência em expressões regulares não me permitiu fazer funcionar

```
sed '* * * * * root /home/linaro/funcao4.sh' /home/linaro/mycron.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sed -i para substituir no próprio arquivo:

```
sed -i '/* * * * * root \/home\/linaro\/funcao4.sh/d' arquivo
```

Answer (score 1):

Poderia utilizar grep na forma:

```
grep -v "* * * * * root /home/linaro/funcao4.sh" /etc/crontab > /home/usuario/mycron
mv /home/usuario/mycron > /etc/crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver ^^

```
sed '/* * * * * root \/home\/linaro\/funcao4.sh/d' /etc/crontab  > /home/linaro/mycron
cat /home/linaro/mycron > /etc/crontab
rm -rf mycron
```